Does complex log(1) have other values than 0?
I want to determine all values of $$ \left[\log \left(3+2 i^{2}\right)\right]^{1-i} $$
First I simplify to $$\left[\log \left(3-2\right)\right]^{1-i}$$
resulting in $$\left[\log \left(1\right)\right]^{1-i}$$ and thus $$0^{1-i}$$ which euqals $0$.
It's part of a former exercise which would give 2 points and I thought that this would be way too easy for getting 2 points.
Also the questions states "determine all solutions" so I assume there must be more than that trivial one.
I tried another way by using the definiton of a complex logarithm:
$$[\log(1)]^{1-i}=[\log\vert1\vert+i\arg(1)+i2\pi k]^{1-i}$$ with $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.
For $k\neq0$ we would have:$$ \left[\log \left(3+2 i^{2}\right)\right]^{1-i} =[i2\pi k]^{1-i}=\exp(\log([i2\pi k]^{1-i})) $$
After a few transformations it would result in
$$i2\pi k\cdot\exp(-i\log(2\pi k))\cdot\exp(2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2})$$ and from here I don't know how to simplify it farther, nor if it's even correct.
Can someone tell if there are more solutions than $0$ at all and if yes, how to determine them?

Note that $e^{ix}=\text{cis}(x)=\text{cos}(x)+i\text{ sin}(x)$.

@underflow, I put it in because I found it useful when I was first learning the connection between complex numbers and trigonometry. I agree it is redundant mathematically but this does not make it redundant in teaching maths, which is a large part of what this forum does.

@underflow, that is hard to remember now; it was over 50 years ago. I think it was partly because the abbreviation made the expanded formula easier to remember, but also because the separate name made it easier to understand that a complex power of a number was an actual thing.

Depends on whether you define $\log$ as a normal single-valued function, or if it is considered multi-valued.
